# SQL Server Instance Related Issue

Tags: sql-server

Hi i'm using SQL server 2008 that was working well. Today when i opened SSMS and tried to connect with server with windows authentication it gives

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to mrdeveloper.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

SQL Server is installed on the same PC it was working 2 days ago but now... however when connect to the express eddition it connects..Kindly guid me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the MSSQLSERVER service is running, if not then start it.

Click Start > Run > type services.msc > hit enter

Comment: it is giving me this error while during run the sql server service **windows could not start the SQL Server on local computer. For more information, review the system event log. if this is a non- Microsoft service, contact the service vender, and refer to service- specific error code 3417**

Comment: in event log I got this SQL error **The log scan number (242:72:1) passed to log scan in database 'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.**

Comment: I googled error 3417 and got this: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/sql-server-2005-expess-how-to-fix-error-3417/
Basically, it is saying that the user account of the SQL Server service does not have access on the /Data/ folder where the master database (.mdf) is located.